# Setting up owncloud + vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, vagrantfile, owncloud

i am trying to setup owncloud on a vagrant machine and i am running into this issue after login in for the first time `Data directory (/var/www/core/data) is readable by other users. Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.`

i tried running `sudo chmod 0770 /var/www/core/data/` with no luck. i am not sure if this has something to do with my vagrant file being like this `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :owner => "www-data"` , maybe some kind of conflit because my shared folder is /var/www ?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added this line and it fixed it for me

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", mount_options: ["dmode=770,fmode=770"]
```